# attributes in form that define in modal does not get dynamic value in laravel :(

Tags: laravel-5, bootstrap-4

I created a table for editing the Movie Object.

One of the table's column is a form that pops up with a modal class (bootstrap)

Here is my code:

```
<div class="modal-body">
<form method="post" action="{{asset(route('movies.update', $movie->id))}}">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
    {{method_field('PATCH')}}

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="movie-name" class="col-form-label">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="movie_name" id="movie-name" placeholder="{{$movie->name}}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="movie-director" class="col-form-label">Direcor:</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="Director">
            @foreach($directors as $director)
            <option value="{{$director->id}}">{{$director->name}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
    <button class="form-control btn btn-success" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
</form></div>
```

When I choose one of the edit buttons, the value of the first item (movie) passes to my controller.

I've tested my code and find out it's happening because I have used the modal class.

Do you have any ideas to solve this problem?